# VSTO: How to add back the VSTO addin once removed being debugged from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsto

I am working on a VSTO Word addin in C#. Recently, I renamed the project and directories, so the Add-in failed to load. I removed the add-in from Word hoping that in next build/run it will get added again. But, now when I run again, it doesn't get added anymore. How can I get back to debugging the addin again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the `bin` and `object` directory from the project folder of Visual Studio forced it to add the addin again in the Word application.

Answer (score 1):

Either rename the project back to the original name

OR

Clean and build the Word addin again so that the Addin is registered again from the newly named folder.

Also, good to ensure that the addin is registered and pointing to the project solution.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins

Comment: Renaming back is not an option as it was done on purpose. Clean and build also didn't bring it back. Will try third option.

Comment: The addin was not present/registered in the registry location mentioned. However, I went ahead and removed all `bin` and `obj` folders from the project folder and Visual Studio added it back. Thanks for the effort.